# Wordpress W3C Total cache - Hide "Purge from Page Cache" in row-actions

Tags: wordpress

I would like to find a way to best hide or remove the "Purge from Page Cache" option which appears in my row-actions once I mouse-over specific posts / pages etc. Does anybody know a way around to have this accomplished?

From what I have noticed the code is generated in the TotalCacheAdmin.php file:

```
/**
 * post_row_actions filter
 *
 * @param array $actions
 * @param object $post
 * @return array
 */
function post_row_actions($actions, $post) {
    $actions = array_merge($actions, array(
        'pgcache_purge' => sprintf('<a href="%s">Purge from Page Cache</a>', wp_nonce_url(sprintf('admin.php?page=w3tc_general&w3tc_pgcache_purge_post&post_id=%d', $post->ID), 'w3tc'))
    ));

    return $actions;
}
```

Some advise would be highly appreciated - thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a display:none option - which does the trick